# cross-compile ghc failed missing iconv

Tags: haskell, ghc

successfully run

```
./configure --target=arm-linux-androideabi --with-gcc=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
```

then make failed.

```
checking value of ENOTSUP... 95
checking value of SIGINT... 2
checking value of O_BINARY... 0
checking for library containing iconv... no
configure: error: iconv is required on non-Windows platforms
make[1]: *** [libraries/base/dist-install/package-data.mk] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Try installing libiconv,and assure that

```
dt-ubt@dt-ubt:~/workspace/ghc$ ls /usr/local/lib/
charset.alias        libiconv.la        libsodium.la             python2.7
libcharset.a         libiconv.so        libsodium.so             python3.4
libcharset.la        libiconv.so.2      libsodium.so.13          site_ruby
libcharset.so        libiconv.so.2.5.0  libsodium.so.13.0.2      x86_64-linux-ghc-7.8.3
libcharset.so.1      libiconv.so.2.5.1  pkgconfig
libcharset.so.1.0.0  libsodium.a        preloadable_libiconv.so
```

but then i ran make,the problem remains.

Specifying the source location of iconv also not works(add it in mk/build.mk)

```
libraries/base_CONFIGURE_OPTS += --configure-option=--with-iconv-includes=/home/dt-ubt/workspace/ghc/iconv/include 
libraries/base_CONFIGURE_OPTS += --configure-option=--with-iconv-libraries=/home/dt-ubt/workspace/ghc/iconv/lib
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need an `iconv` matching `arm-linux-androideabi`. Speculatively: if GHC links `iconv` into compiled Haskell binaries, then that copy of iconv must match the `--target` architecture.

Comment: where does ghc find the corresponding libiconv.so and how does it check the target?

Comment: @doofin As NDK lacks iconv yet (planned to be included in future releases), you should either build it from scratch or link in an existing library that supports the interface. Currently I'm doing the exact same thing you are attempting to achieve. Will post updates.